# How do I decode this! It's not base64

Tags: php, decode

Here's what I know...

this "GxvS117MfVw=" when decoded turns to "56699"

now what does this "+sB6hF46GyU=" turn into "?????"

" not included

I tried base64 decoder and it doesn't seem to be right. It is supposed to be a number. I am not sure about the length, I don't think it should exceed 5 numbers. I would really appreciate it if you can decode it for me and show me how. Thank you!!

**Edit:**

I understand this might be insufficient data as this is my first post. Well I think it's php and its encoded like this

pubcredentials.php?id=GxvS117MfVw=

Please provide of the info you need and i'll try as much as I can to get it

**Edit 1:**

I got another one "L0sgBFUTpsE=" turns to "53096"

" not included

I am getting asked why would "L0sgBFUTpsE=" turns to "53096" Just to let you know that I did not decode this. This info was available to me when I was able to it decode it before they changed their decoding methods. So those are TRUE!

Comment: This also a wrong thing, this "GxvS117MfVw=" when decoded turns to "56699".  So give more thing about your need

Comment: It sure looks like base64, are you sure it's not encrypted and "base64:ed"?

Comment: No, I'm 100% sure it's right. I checked again... I did not decode this. I already have it.

Comment: @Don you are right. It does look like base64. That's what I thought at first but when i encoded 56699 it did not turn out like this "GxvS117MfVw=" Which is what it should.

Comment: My question is, why do you need this? If you had legitimate access to the ID, you'd know how it's generated. Looks to me like you're trying to feed someone else's site some values....I'm not going to help with that.

Comment: @Jan Kuboschek That's fine.. only who is willing to help...

Comment: Parentheses != quotation marks

Answer (score 3):

If the data represents Base-64 encoded material, the bytes encoded in the string are:

```
$ b64 -d "+sB6hF46GyU=" 
Base64:
0x0000: +sB6hF46GyU=
Binary:
0x0000: FA C0 7A 84 5E 3A 1B 25 00                        ..z.^:.%.
$
```

For reference, the same program decodes the other set as:

```
$ b64 -d "GxvS117MfVw="
Base64:
0x0000: GxvS117MfVw=
Binary:
0x0000: 1B 1B D2 D7 5E CC 7D 5C 00                        ....^.}\.
$
```

Consequently, I'm not sure how you came up with the answer 56699 that you claim it means in the question.

I needed to work with Base-64 stuff, and wrote the program to suit my particular needs at the time.

For details on Base 64, see [RFC3548](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3548.txt).

Each group of 4 Base-64 encoded characters represents 1-3 bytes of binary (unencoded) data.
The strings you give are both 12 bytes long, representing 7-9 bytes of binary data.  The strings actually encode just 8 bytes; the '=' at the end means that what would otherwise be the 9th byte is not present.

From the RFC:

```
               Table 1: The Base 64 Alphabet

  Value Encoding  Value Encoding  Value Encoding  Value Encoding
      0 A            17 R            34 i            51 z
      1 B            18 S            35 j            52 0
      2 C            19 T            36 k            53 1
      3 D            20 U            37 l            54 2
      4 E            21 V            38 m            55 3
      5 F            22 W            39 n            56 4
      6 G            23 X            40 o            57 5
      7 H            24 Y            41 p            58 6
      8 I            25 Z            42 q            59 7
      9 J            26 a            43 r            60 8
     10 K            27 b            44 s            61 9
     11 L            28 c            45 t            62 +
     12 M            29 d            46 u            63 /
     13 N            30 e            47 v
     14 O            31 f            48 w         (pad) =
     15 P            32 g            49 x
     16 Q            33 h            50 y
```

So, 'GxvS' is:

```
6        49       47       18
000110   110001   101111   010010
```

Regrouping:

```
000110.11  0001.1011   11.010010
```

Interpreted as hex:

```
0x1B  0x1B  0xD2
```

Which is what my program gave as the first three bytes.

If I had to guess, you've got an 8-byte 'integer' encoded in Base-64 instead of decimal.  And it is not a direct mapping to the 56699; it is some sort of session identifier that is associated with the ID 56699.

Comment: I confess to puzzlement - why a drive by down-vote for an explanation of what the encoded data actually represents?

Comment: Well all I know is that I used to be able to decode it, using the info I provided, but it seems that recently they have changed their methods and I got out of luck I guess

Answer (score 1):

Even though the strings look like if there are [`base64`-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) - based on the character repertoire given in the examples above and the distinctive `=` character(s) at the end of the string - the transformation `56699 --> GxvS117MfVw=` might consist of several steps including compression and/or encryption algorithms with a `base64`-encoding as its last step.

So as [VeeBee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955697/how-do-i-decode-this-its-not-base64/2955727#2955727) said: without any further information it's impossible to identify the steps required for the way back `GxvS117MfVw= --> 56699`.

Comment: Would be nice to explain why an answer is down-voted... But that would require some understanding of the original problem and the answer posted (this is especially true for the ones who down-voted Jonathan Leffler answer as it explains what can be explained given the original question).

Comment: +1 Solidarity upvote :) (I see no reason why this was downvoted)